# Swift filter NSfetchedResultController CoreData return record in specific an array

Tags: arrays, core-data, mapreduce

Hi I'm about to build a magazine app. I have an API to return top stories as array of NSManageObject (`items`). How to construct `fetchrequest` of NSFetchedResultController to fetch record from coredata which return only the record that is in the array `items`? (or record which has id in item.id) Any help is much appreciate! Thanks

something like `fetchRequest.predicate == NSPredicate....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to the object being evaluated, use "SELF".  So the predicate would be something like:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF IN %@", argumentArray:[items])
```

or if you have an array of `id`s:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"id IN %@", argumentArray:[arrayOfIds])
```

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh Have added the predicate for an array of ids.

Comment: thanks, the 2nd work just fine. 1 last question if i have a network api core (for example an Alamofire that return list of id that the predicate should be in. Where should i put the code to update the predicate value so that tableview data will show up accordingly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AlamoFire, but presumably it has some form of completion handler which is executed once the network request has been fulfilled.  You should update the predicate there.  You will also need to call `performFetch` on the FRC because it will not respond automatically to changes to the predicate.  And then call `reloadData` on the tableView.

Comment: is the reformFetch enough? I thought FRC will automatic update the tableview with the updated coredata? I'm trying to avoid reloaddata for big tableview

Comment: No, if you performFetch you will need to reload the table, otherwise they will become out of sync.  The FRC only does automatic updates if it observes changes to any of its underlying objects.  In your case, the objects do not change.  The only way the FRC will recognise the change to the predicate is if you call performFetch.  Rather than capture the ids and use them in the predicate, you could instead update an attribute (eg. "downloaded") on the relevant CoreData objects.  Use that attribute in the predicate.  The FRC will then recognise that change and update the tableView accordingly.

Comment: so that mean if for example i have api return list of id for topstories, new stories, best stories. I should make attribute like "feature" an store when insert in core data? but some item can be both top and best and new at the same time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122325/discussion-between-pbasdf-and-le-khanh-vinh).